# Unconsistent values of parameter - Azure API App Client calls locally IIS Hosted API

Tags: c#, ajax, azure, iis

I have been sitting all day and can not figure this out. I have made seaches on stackoverflow and the web but have found no answers.

**Setup**

This is not the optimal setup but it is what I have to deal with because of legacy code.

I have a FileController (API controller) class hosted on the client web that is used to upload files. A MVC Controller is making a jquery.ajax call throug angular to the FileController.UploadFiles(). The FileController.UploadFiles() get some data out from the database and then send a request to the storageAPI which store the file in a blob in a certain way depending on the settings parameter inside the CustomResponse object.

The problem is that the parameter CustomResponse is null sometimes when it gets to the controller and sometimes I actually has a value. It's seems to be totally random.

I have tested it manually by clicking a upload button on my Client GUI that calls the FileController with Ajax which in turn calls the API. Both the client web and the storage api is hosted locally and hosted on a local IIS. Can it be a collision?

It's not null when I use the Swagger UI to do posts. Then it gets the content parameter everytime.

The request always reach the Storage API when i debug. So the "wiring" between them is fine.

I have tried to do both async and not async calls and have change the method in the API also to be sync and async no difference.

**Code**

Code

FileController (CLIENT)

```
byte[] fileBytes = null;
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
var fileBytesString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
var settingsString = "renditions:large,thumbail;assettype:testdataimage;testdataid:" + testData.Id.ToString() + ";filename:" + fileName;

var client = new StorageAPI();
client.BaseUri = new Uri("http://storageapi.mycompany.local/");

CustomResponse response = null;

response = client.Blob.Post(new CustomRequest()
{
     FileBytesString = fileBytesString,
     Settings = settingsString
});

client.Dispose();
```

StorageAPI Model CustomRequest

```
public class CustomRequest
{
    public string FileBytesString { get; set; }
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

StorageAPI Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(CustomResponse))]
[Route("api/Blob/")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(CustomRequest content)
{
    if (content == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    //Parse data and upload file to blob.

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I'm looking forward to get some feedback to what I'm doing wrong here.

Regards

Comment: My first thought would be to capture some traffic and see what is happening on the wire, either through postman or native packet capture. Do you know if it is failing the (content == null) ?

Comment: I installed postman and it works as expected (just as it does in the swagger UI). So it seems there is something wrong with the Azure API Client that is produced or in the way I'm using it.

Comment: Can you capture traffic between the API Client and the http://storageapi.mycompany.local/ endpoint? see what traffic the API Client is sending

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your helpful comments that leed me in the right direction.

I configured both the API and the Web to go through the Fiddler Proxy and looked at the request and nothing that matter was different.

Then I again started to look at the content I'm sending (pictures) and it turns out it is a size issue, the larger picture did not go through but the smaller did not. I searched for what the default size is for a ASP.NET application and it is 4096 kB and one of my images was larger than that!

This line in the web.config in the system.web section solved the problem.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="8192"/>
```

This has been a good learning for me and I hope it might help someone else that is new to this sending large files over the wire thing!

Thanks!